# to find pair of integers in an array having maximum sum

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there any way to find the pair of integers in an array whose sum will be max.Is there algorithm that we can use?.Kindly suggest me on this.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: This would be the two largest integers.

Comment: I think Manoj is asking for the following:  Given an array of integers A of length N, find i such that A[i] + A[i+1] is a maximum, 0 <= i < N.  This can be done naively in O(N) time.

Answer (score 0):

here's some pseudocode:

```
function max_pair_sum( a array of int, x as int by ref, y as int by ref ){

// x is biggest
// y is second biggest

x = y = null

foreach value in a
  if x is null
    x = value
  elseif y is null
    if x >= value
      y = value
    else 
      y = x
      x = value
    endif
  else // both x and y have values now
    if x >= value
      if y < value
         y = value
      endif
    else
      y = x
      x = value
    endif
  endif
endfor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned by Gordon, if your language has a sort method, simply sort and pick the two highest values.